# Azure Tomcat CGI Error, works fine locally

Tags: java, azure, tomcat7, cgi

Running on my PC everything is fine, but deployed to Azure, I get only this error:

> The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server
>   terminated the process.

as response for queries while no other logging or error message can be found.

On my PC, Tomcat is starting up and running at about 1.5G memory.

I played around using custom `web.config` but I did not have success, which may be caused by the fact that I'm not sure where to put this file in the first place...

Comment: are you using Free or Shared web sites ? with requirement of about 1.5G Memory, you should use at least B2 basic tier servers: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/websites/

Comment: I tried various tiers, including B2...

Comment: and Standard tier using 64bit Java

Comment: did you manage to solve it?